# Building application in Visual Studio 2012 always generates unwanted dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

I am making changes to a web forms application in visual studio 2012 and part of that change is to remove reference to an old dll. The dll is responsible for handling authentication and I have written a new class library to handle this.

My problem is everytime I build my website in the solution, it always generates this old dll. I've annotated out all references to it in the entire application and it's not in the project dependencies of the solution.

If I exclude the unwanted dll, it just generates a new one. I am completely baffled by this. It's something I've not encountered before so I am not sure what else I can do.

I'm not sure what to post so if anyone can help then that would be great.

Comment: Does it shows up in the .csproj or .vbproj when you open up with a simple text editor like notepad?

Comment: Is there any other projects referenced that are using that dll as well? Say a utilities class library or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (but it was with a persistent DB file being generated). I ended up having to go through the **bin** from the project file and **editing** it from there. Some files are 'hidden' from the project, and are either visible by

> Make sure you are showing all files. There is a button at the top of
>   the Solution Explorer called "Show All Files". To see this button,
>   make sure that your project is selected in the solution explorer.

or by manually going through your project files.

**EDIT**

It can sometimes be hidden in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) where it can reside indefinitely. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zykhfde0.aspx explains how to remove it (if it is indeed hiding there).

Answer (score -1):

try this, remove the old project from your Solution.